is there a way to only select the value from a dictionary from a json file?
i have a website which im hosting with flask and using mongodb to store data. i am using htmx to reset the data, but i am running into a problem; when the data resets, it shows the entire dictionary, when i only want the value from the dictionary. it seems like it would be an easy fix, but because i am so new to htmx i have no idea what to do.
heres my current flask setup:
@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    return json.loads(dumps(collection.find()))

and my html:
<h1>MongoDB Data Test</h1>
<div id="data-container" 
   hx-get="/data" 
   hx-trigger="load, every 3s" 
   hx-target="#data-container" 
   hx-swap="innerHTML">
   <!-- Data will be injected here -->
   <span></span>
</div>

this is what is shown on the website:
[ { "_id": { "$oid": "id" }, "count_testing": 15 } ]
i only want the count_testing value (i.e. 15), not the entire dictionary to be shown on the website.

what is dumps?

its from bson.json_util

Are you using jinja2 or pywebview or any other module or framework?

im using flask, jinja2, and htmx to reload data from mongodb

The best way to do it would be on the Python side IMO. Put data in a variable, run a list comprehension on it, return the output. Like:
def get_data():
    data = list(collection.find()) 
    filtered_data = [item['count_testing'] for item in data if 'count_testing' in item]
    return jsonify(filtered_data)


how can i remove the list brackets? its not that big of a deal as this is produces a very clean result, but if it is possible to remove the list brackets this solution would be great. im guessing its only possible to remove the brackets on the html side.

also, how would i make this work for multiple items?

At this point it's just standard python programming. Ask Chatgpt

@user26831591 ','.join(filtered_data) will turn the list into a comma-separated string.

@Barmar i cant use ', '.join(filtered_data) for my data because .join doesnt allow integers. however, this is easily fixed by using ', '.join(map(str, filtered_data)). the map functions turns each value into a str, which allows me to use .join.
this does show quotations on the website instead of brackets, which you can also fix with by returning a Response with plain text, i.e. return Response(data_string, mimetype='text/plain')
however, i have a question; what if i wanted to use completely separate values? would i need to store the values in completely different directories?

to clarify, lets say i have two values in the same collection: count_testing and message_count. while i could easily extract both counts from the mongodb database, they will always be together. i want it to show on the website like this:
test count: (count_testing value) message count: (message_count value). would i need to use two different app routes?

nevermind, solved! extract data you need into a list via list comprehension (or other method), and then you can specify the indexes in the list as well as adding a break to seperate the values: data_string = f'count: {filtered_data[0]}<br>message_count: {filtered_data[1]}' make sure to return it in plain text via Response


collection.find() returns a cursor object containing documents.
Please note: each document has fields and values. for instance if you want to get all the field,value dict of first object, you need to call collection.find()[0] which returns a dict
dct = collection.find()[0]
print(dct)
# Output:    {'a':1, 'b':2}


By using  return json.loads(dumps(collection.find())) you are converting the dict to json string and in turn converting into a dict.


What I mean to say is get specific document and return the values. For eg.,
@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    cursor = collection.find()

    # access document with specific index or specific _id or query. I used index 0
    dct = cursor[0] 

    # values = [x for x in dct.values()]
    # Edited as you want specific value
    val = dct['count_testing']
    return val


[x for x in dct.values()] can be simplified to just list(dct.values())

How does this return just the count_testing fields?

See my edited answer @Barmar

You can simply index the object to only return the value you're interested in:
@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    return str(json.loads(json.dumps(collection.find()))[0]["count_testing"])


"TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a int."

Fixed it, thanks, I didn't test the code
